# Hide subfolder in URL with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL structure like this: `www.mydomain.com/foo/bar/index`

and I want achieve this: `www.mydomain.com/bar/index`

I already have a rewrite rule like this to remove `.php` from the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ $1.php
```

So, how can I add a new rule to hide the `foo` subfolder in compliance with the rule already implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. Put this before your existing RewriteRules

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^bar/ /foo%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: This is resulting in `/foo/bar/bar`, changing to `RewriteRule ^bar/ /foo%{REQUEST_URI} [L]` I think will do the trick.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do that to all subfolders inside `foo`? A global `RewriteRule` for `bar`, `bar2`, `bar3` or any other subfolder inside `foo`? So I don't have to update the `.htaccess` file each time I create a new subfolder..

Comment: If you are trying to rewrite multiple subfolders, you may replace the pattern with this : **^(bar|bar1|bar2|)$**

Answer (score 0):

You can have your htaccess as this one:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add /foo/ if not there
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^foo/ foo%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

# add .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```